# Are there any plans for the 'groups.link' attribute to return MS Graph API URLs?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm integrating Azure Active Directory's SAML SSO with my application. If the user has more than 150 groups then the Groups Overage Indicator is returned, as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-saml-tokens). However the link from the `groups.link` attribute is using the old Azure AD Graph API, rather than the new MS Graph one. The Azure AD Graph API is deprecated and set to be removed in June, in addition it's somewhat tricky to manage as one cannot add API permissions to the app without using workarounds like the Powershell client.

I have the user id on hand, so I could just construct a MS Graph API URL by hand, however as the Azure AD Graph API is on its way out, I assume at some point the `groups.link` attribute would either cease to exist or return a MS Graph API URL. Are there any plans to update the return value of the `groups.link` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this Link which gives new Microsoft Graph one for fetching the details of members of a particular groups [MS Graph Groups](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bid%7D/members?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName,%20%27a%27)) .

Comment: The link works for me, I have no problems with making a call using the MS Graph API, the thing is that the SAML response returns a link which uses the old API, which will soon reach end of life. I'm wondering if I can expect the SAML response to return an MS Graph API link which would allow me to use it rather than build the URL manually.

Comment: Can you please share the client Id, request Id and the screenshot of the output which you are getting.